# Negative z-index on :after pseudo element breaks CSS :hover transition animation

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations, css-transitions

I was trying to make an animated sidebar with hover, when the mouse goes over the sidebar list item a colored box slides in from the side. For this purpose I used the :after pseudo element to use as the sliding box however it covered the text of the list item. To fix this I set the z-index value of the :after pseudo element to -1. As soon as I made the change the transitions broke, they ease-in without a problem but as soon as the mouse leaves the area, the colored box jumps back immediately without an exit transition. The only thing that works is when keeping the mouse inside of it's parent.

Here's the html

```
<nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="list-group-flush" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar-item active" href="/home">
            <div class="sidebar-item-content">
                <i class="fas fa-home sidebar-item-icon"></i>
                <span class="sidebar-item-text">Home</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar-item" href="/trending">
            <div class="sidebar-item-content">
                <i class="fas fa-trophy sidebar-item-icon"></i>
                <span class="sidebar-item-text">Trending</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar-item" href="/create_challenge">
            <div class="sidebar-item-content">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle sidebar-item-icon"></i>
                <span class="sidebar-item-text">Create Challenge</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar-item" href="/profile">
            <div class="sidebar-item-content">
                <i class="fas fa-user-circle sidebar-item-icon"></i>
                <span class="sidebar-item-text">Profile</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the SCSS

```
#sidebar {
height: 100vh;
width: $left-bar-width;
padding-top: spacer(3);
position: fixed;
box-shadow: 0 0 $shadow-spread 0 $shadow-color;
z-index: 1;
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, add($left-bar-width,$shadow-spread) 0%, add($left-bar-width,$shadow-spread) 

100%, 0% 100%);
}

.sidebar-item-content{
    padding: $sidebar-item-content-padding;
    &:before{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: $sidebar-item-padding-y;
        right: $sidebar-item-padding-x;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-out;
        width: 0%;
        height: subtract(100%,2*$sidebar-item-padding-y);
        border-radius: $sidebar-item-content-roundness;
        background-color: $sidebar-item-content-color;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    &:hover{
        &:before{
            width: subtract(100%,2*$sidebar-item-padding-x);
        }
    }
}

.sidebar-item{
    padding: 
        $sidebar-item-padding-y 
        $sidebar-item-padding-x 
        $sidebar-item-padding-y 
        $sidebar-item-padding-x;
    &.list-group-item{
        border: none;
    }
    &.list-group-item:hover,:focus{
        background-color: initial;
        color: initial;
    }
    &.active{
        &.list-group-item{
            z-index: initial;
            background-color: initial;
            color: initial;
        }
        .sidebar-item-content{
            &:before{
                width: $sidebar-item-active-width;
            }
            .sidebar-item-icon{
                fill: $sidebar-item-content-color;
            }
            .sidebar-item-text{
                color: $sidebar-item-content-color;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help, I admit I'm completely stumped on this one.

Comment: Hi could you put your code in a `jsfiddle` for debug purpose ? it would be great.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar Sorry for the delay just woke up, anyways, here's a codepen link: https://codepen.io/kevbot30001/pen/bGVWmQB

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, the parent element had to have a z-index of 2, basically, parent z-index - 1 had to be greater than 0 which was not the case before.